# Display image only if it enter in some define position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one vertical slider page.
in every slide I have one image and I have iphone container.
like

[image: demo]

[image]

now this page slides vertically show next slides comes in center and its also contains image on center.

now I want something like that image only displayed when its comes in iphone container.

as here in second image my images showing even out of iphone container so I dont want to do that

my code

```
<div style="display: block; position: fixed; top: 14.5px; left: 684px;" class="iphone_container"><img title="" src="/img/iphon.png"></div>


<div class="port_list">
        <div class="port_wrap" id="slide_1" style="background-color: #344a18;position: relative">
            <div class="proj_brief"></div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="">
                    <img src="" />                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="port_wrap" id="slide_1" style="background-color: #344a18;position: relative">
            <div class="proj_brief"></div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="">
                    <img src="" />                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="port_wrap" id="slide_1" style="background-color: #344a18;position: relative">
            <div class="proj_brief"></div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="">
                    <img src="" />                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post some code to show what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You create a container div for your phone and put there a div for the sildes. with overflow:hidden you can hide the additional content.

```
<div id="phone">
  <div id="slides">
      <img src="pic1.png" />
      <img src="pic2.png" />
      <img src="pic3.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="slide up" onclick="slide('up')" />
<input type="button" value="slide down" onclick="slide('down')" />
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qfzBk/2/

Comment: i have more than 1 slide and those are sliding vertically

Comment: oh come on...this the solution. i won't code the hole thing for you. if you want this from me, i'll give you my contact for an offer... just wrap another slide around it...